# Every 5 months recurrent rule with later.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, laterjs

I want to create schedule every 5 month. so i try this:

```
var startDate = new Date("2015-07-13T15:58:30.546Z");
var s = later.parse.recur().every(5).month();
s.on(startDate.getDate()).dayOfMonth();
var nextDates = later.schedule(s).next(3, startDate);
console.log(nextDates);
```

I'm expecting to get this result:

```
[ Fri Jul 13 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST),
  Wed Dec 13 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST),
  Mon May 13 2016 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT) ]
```

But the code above produce this result:

```
[ Sun Nov 13 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST),
  Fri Jan 13 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST),
  Wed Jun 13 2016 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT) ]
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

May be use `startingOn`:

```
later.parse.recur()
 .every(5).month()
 .on(startDate.getDate()).dayOfMonth()
 .startingOn(startDate.getMonth() + 1)
```

Added 1 since months are indexed from 0.